# REST Web Service in C# class library

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create a **REST Webservice**, not sure to create a separate **WebAPI** or just add a **WCF Service**.

```
public class FirstService : Reactor, IFirstService
{
    const string StateFilename = "DetectedEvent.bin";

    public string Reset()
    {
        string stateFile = Path.Combine(App.StoragePath, StateFilename);
        if (File.Exists(stateFile))
        {
            File.Delete(stateFile);
        }

        return "Reset Completed";
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a webservice for deleting a file and that call I would be doing using Powershell **Invoke-RestMethod** 
The **DetectedEvent.bin** is located in remote server.

I have already created a C# class library i.e. custom **Seq.App.FirstOfType** but now I want to create a REST webservice by which wen called can delete a file.

I am using Seq App, Seq has a storagePath which it stores all data, which I want to delete it.

Please someone can let me know how should I go forward i.e should I create new project i.e. **WEBAPI** and attach it to current solution or I should create a **WCF service application**.

Comment: Web API seems like the more logical choice for a REST service.

Comment: @DanWilson: Thanks for help. So I should add Asp.net webapi and attach it to my C# class library already created.?

Comment: Putting them in the same solution seems reasonable.

Comment: @DanWilson: Ok will try that. also if you have any examples which you know then please let me know, I will really appreciate it. (But I will definitely search documentation for it)